# Strings comparing unequal when they are equal

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program to do a brute force solution to the TSP, and as part of it I need to find a graph edge based on the destination name.  `r->destcity` and `tofind->name` are both `std::strings`, and actually the equal ones are both assigned using the same string from input in another part of the code.  My code is as follows:

```
Edge findEdge(vector<Vertex>::iterator tofind){
    for (vector<Edge>::iterator r = Edges.begin(); r < Edges.end(); r++){
        cout << r->destcity << " " << tofind->name << " ";//This and the next 
        cout << ((r->destcity == tofind->name)?"True":"False") << endl; //line are for debugging
        if (r->destcity == tofind->name)
            return *r;
}
    cerr << "Didn't find edge\n";
exit(200);
}
```

However, the strings never compare as equal, despite being equal.  For reference, here's the diagnostic cout output:

```
New York New York False <- This should return true
Miami New York False
Seattle New York False
```

EDIT:  The problem wasn't actually with this part of the program, one of the strings is preceded by unprintable characters.  Since that is an I/O issue I will ask a separate question if I can't figure out why that's happening.

Comment: You may need to look in both strings to see if either one contains an unprintable character.

Comment: Are the strings *std::string* or C-style char pointers?

Comment: @hyde they're given in the question as `std::string` but that would explain things if they weren't.

Comment: This is where a debugger would come in handy.

Comment: Mark is correct, for some reason there are 3 unprintable characters in front of r->name when I try to print it out character by character.

Comment: Are `Vertex::name` and `Edge::destcity` actually `std::string`s? Or are they maybe `std::string*`?

Comment: There are two possibilities:  either there's a bug in the standard library implementation used by millions of programmers every day, or there is something wrong with your assumptions.  Which do you think is the case here?

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure this is the only problem, but your iteration loop is using the wrong comparison:

```
for (vector<Edge>::iterator r = Edges.begin(); r < Edges.end(); r++){
```

This won't work, because the iterators aren't necessarily "in order", i.e. `Edges.end()` isn't necessarily "bigger" than all other elements in there.

This would be the correct loop:

```
for (vector<Edge>::iterator r = Edges.begin(); r != Edges.end(); r++){
```

Note this is using the operator `!=` to loop as long as the end isn't reached.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought this might be the case but hadn't had any problems yet.  I'll go ahead and change that in the program.

Comment: Using `<` can be perfectly fine when testing, but might break later on. It really depends on the implementation runtime conditions (like free memory addresses).

Comment: Are you sure about this? Vector iterators are random-access iterators, so they should support < meaningfully.

Comment: Hm, true. It should actually be fine for vectors and pointers (and as long as you don't change your container).